# How to deploy an Nx Angular monorepo with Vercel or Netlify?

Tags: angular, netlify, vercel, nrwl-nx

I'm working on a side project using Angular via Nrwl Nx. Everything was going great until I tried to deploy the thing.

I looked at the docs for a long time and couldn't find anything about deploying an Nx project. So I went to Vercel and just tried to set it up. It seemed to be working, but it can't even install the project.

This is the error I get:

```
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Incorrect or missing password.
npm ERR! If you were trying to login, change your password, create an
npm ERR! authentication token or enable two-factor authentication then
npm ERR! that means you likely typed your password in incorrectly.
npm ERR! Please try again, or recover your password at:
npm ERR!     https://www.npmjs.com/forgot
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you were doing some other operation then your saved credentials are
npm ERR! probably out of date. To correct this please try logging in again with:
npm ERR!     npm login
```

I tried to set it up with Netlify, but I get the same exact error.

I don't understand what is going on, why do I get a login error during `npm i` or `npm ci`?

It's all very standard, just an nx Angular monorepo with 2 libraries to separate the core app code from the code I'm using for view components.

Comment: Can you share the output of the `npm config get registry` command

Answer (score 0):

With NX you'll need to override Vercel's `Build & Development Settings` to use NX commands. This is for example:
[image]